# Evaluating the integral $\int_{1/3}^3 \frac{\tan^{-1}(x) } {1+x^2-x} \, dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

Would like some help in evaluating the integral $$\int_{1/3}^3 \frac{\tan^{-1}x}{ 1-x+x^2} \, dx$$

Comment: Have you tried anything?  A change-of-variables?

Comment: Given how nonelementary the antiderivative is per [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+arctan%28x%29%2F%281-x%2Bx%5E2%29), and how Wolfram can only seem to offer an approximation for the definite integral, I'm wondering what you have tried and where you found this. I really doubt elementary methods, e.g. $u$-sub, would work here as well.

Answer (score 1):

Changing $u=\frac{1}{x}$, we get:

$$\int_{1/3}^3 \frac{\tan^{-1}x}{ 1-x+x^2} \, dx=\int_{1/3}^3 \frac{\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{u}}{ 1-u+u^2} \, du$$

Therefore, using $\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1} \frac{1}{x}=\frac{\pi}{2}$ for $x>0$, we get:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{1/3}^3 \frac{\tan^{-1}x}{ 1-x+x^2} \, dx &= \frac{1}{2}\int_{1/3}^3 \frac{\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}x}{ 1-x+x^2} \, dx\\
&= \frac{\pi}{4}\int_{1/3}^3 \frac{1}{ 1-x+x^2} \, dx
\end{aligned}
$$

Can you end it now?

Answer (score 0):

$$
\int_{1/3}^3 \frac{\tan^{-1}(x)}{ 1-x+x^2} \, dx = \int_{1/3}^3 \frac{\tan^{-1}(x)}{ (1/x)-1+x} \cdot \frac{dx} x
$$
\begin{align}
& x = 1/u \\[6pt]
& dx = -du/u^2 \\[6pt]
& \frac{dx} x = -\frac {du} u \\[6pt]
& \text{As } x \text{ goes from } 1/3 \text{ to } 3, \\
& u \text{ goes from } 3 \text{ to } 1/3. \\[6pt]
& \tan^{-1} x = \frac\pi 2 - \tan^{-1} u
\end{align}
So the integral becomes
\begin{align}
& \int_3^{1/3} \frac{\frac\pi2 - \tan^{-1}(u)}{u - 1 + (1/u)} \cdot\frac{-du} u \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac \pi 2\int_{1/3}^3 \frac{-du}{u^2-u+1} + \int_{1/3}^3 \frac{\tan^{-1}(u)}{u^2-u+1} \, du  
\end{align}
So
$$
\Big(\text{original integral} \Big) = -\frac \pi 2 \int_{1/3} \frac{du}{u^2-u+1} +\Big(\text{original integral} \Big)
$$
Therefore
\begin{align}
2\times\Big(\text{original integral}\Big) & = \frac{-\pi}2\int_{1/3}^3 \frac{du}{u^2 - u + 1} \\[8pt]
& = \frac{-\pi} 2\int_{1/3}^3 \frac{du}{\left( u - \frac 1 2 \right)^2 + \frac 3 4}
\end{align}
etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. One may recall that
$$
\tan^{-1}\frac1x=\frac \pi2-\tan^{-1}x,\quad x>0,
$$ then, performing the change of variable $\displaystyle x \to \frac 1x$, gives easily
$$
I:=\int_{1/3}^3 \frac{\tan^{-1}x}{ 1-x+x^2} \, dx=\int_{1/3}^3 \frac{\frac \pi2-\tan^{-1}x}{ 1-\frac1x+\frac1{x^2}} \, \frac{dx}{x^2}=\frac \pi2\int_{1/3}^3 \frac{1}{ 1-x+x^2} \, dx-I.
$$